# How to add new element to the next empty index in 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array:

```
String[][] ProductAllData1 = new String[10][6]; //This array takes input 10 times
```

This array may usually get an input like `{"John", "Mary", "Bonny", "Sadie", "Dutch", "Arthur"}`

My question is how can I insert another input like this on the array's next empty index?

I think may need an incrementing  index for this but I'm not sure how to do it in terms of using for loop for the next iteration (it's like for every iteration, a new input is going to be inserted into the next empty index.

Comment: please explain what you are trying to achieve , outside the code part .

Answer (score 1):

As you said, use a `for` loop and have a loop variable which increments for every iteration. Use this variable as the index of the array.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    String[] input = null; // replace this null with the input
    array[i] = input;
}
```

You could use a similar loop with a different loop variable to get the elements of `input` array

Answer (score 1):

The array is defined as a `String[][]` with 10 rows, each row having 6 elements.

The first row provided has six names.

If the array must take another 9 elements you need a way to increment the first index. The easiest way would be with a variable.

```
String[][] arr = new String[10][6];
boolean moreInput = true;
for (int i = 0; i < 10 && moreInput; i++) {
    arr[i] = ... ; // get the input you need for index i
    moreInput = ... ; // ask the user or whatever process it is that is populating the array if there is more input to read into the array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the outer array and find the next element with an empty inner array. You can do this by testing if the outer element is pointing to `null` or to an array with no elements.

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < ProductAllData1.length; i++) {
        if (ProductAllData1[i] == null || ProductAllData1[i].length == 0) {
            ProductAllData[i] = inputArray;
        }
    }
```

- `ProductAllData1[i] == null` -> the outer element points to nothing
- `ProductAllData1[i].length == 0` -> the outer element points to an inner array with no elements